# How to get caller function class name

Tags: javascript

I tried some thing following, it fullfils 80% of the need though not enough to use.

```
// Different file
function A(){}

A.prototype.ao = function(){
    // Here I want ot know the fucntion caller class name, for that I used
    arguments.callee.caller.prototype; // It retuens B.bo {} (object)
}

// Different file
function B(){}
B.prototype.bo = function(){
    var a = new A();
    a.ao();
}
```

How to retrieve the class name from caller prototype, as it is of type object.

I would be more helpful, if we able to get the caller function context.

Comment: This is almost certainly the X/Y problem: You want to do X, and you think you can do that by doing Y, but you're having trouble doing Y and so asked how to do it. But if we knew what X was, we could almost certainly suggest a better way than Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to retrive the class name from caller prototype

You can't*, for a couple of reasons:

1. Functions don't have a `name` property. [They will in ES6](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-function-instances-name), but they don't yet. (You could assign a property to `B` with the name, though.)
2. Although you can get a reference to the function that's on `B.prototype.bo`, there's no link from there back to `B`. The linkage is one-way. (Not least because the same function could be on multiple objects.)

Note that using `arguments.callee` is **strongly discouraged**, and disallowed in strict mode, and using `caller` is **especially** discouraged. There's almost always a better way to do what you're trying to do.

---

* On **some** engines, you might be able to figure it out from the call stack, e.g.:

```
A.prototype.ao = function(){
    try {
        throw new Error();
    }
    catch (e) {
        // Examine e.stack here
    }
};
```

You'd be relying on platform-specific naming and such.

But again, there's almost certainly a better option than trying to know who's calling you.

---

Re your comment:

> Here my requirement is to track an API function usage, in order to achieve it I am following this way...And further I can't change the existed framework.

You probably can but don't realize it, because JavaScript is **that** powerful. :-)

For instance: Once whatever framework creates `B` is loaded on the page, here's code that will wrap every function on `B.prototype` with a version that tells you it's running:

```
function wrapFunctions(name, proto) {
    Object.keys(proto).forEach(function(key) {
        var original = proto[key];
        if (typeof original === "function") {
            proto[key] = function() {
                var rv;
                starting(name, key);    // <=== Your function to tracking the start of a call
                rv = original.apply(this, arguments);
                stopping(name, key);    // <=== Your function tracking the end of the call
                return rv;
            };
        }
    });
}
wrapFunctions("B", B.prototype);
```

That's the beginning of "instrumentation." But note that there are proper libraries out there for this that have solved the edge cases and such.

**Live Example**:

```js
// The framework
function B() {}
B.prototype.f1 = function() {
  snippet.log("Original functionality for f1");
};
B.prototype.f2 = function() {
  snippet.log("Original functionality for f2");
};
B.prototype.f3 = function() {
  snippet.log("Original functionality for f3 -- calling f2");
  this.f2();
  snippet.log("Original functionality for f3 -- done calling f2");
};

// Let's use f1 and f2 before we wrap them
snippet.log("Before wrapping:");
var b1 = new B();
b1.f1();
b1.f2();
b1.f3();

// Now your code runs and wraps them
wrapFunctions("B", B.prototype);

// Now let's use f1 and f2 again
snippet.log("After wrapping:");
var b2 = new B();
b2.f1();
b2.f2();
b1.f3();

// Our function to track that a call started
function starting(ctor, name) {
  snippet.log(ctor + "#" + name + ": Started");
}

// Our function to track that a call stopped
function stopping(ctor, name) {
  snippet.log(ctor + "#" + name + ": Stopped");
}

// Our function to wrap things
function wrapFunctions(name, proto) {
  Object.keys(proto).forEach(function(key) {
    var original = proto[key];
    if (typeof original === "function") {
      proto[key] = function() {
        var rv;
        starting(name, key); // <=== Your function to tracking the start of a call
        rv = original.apply(this, arguments);
        stopping(name, key); // <=== Your function tracking the end of the call
        return rv;
      };
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Crowder: thanks for the answer. Here my requirement is to track an API function usage, in order to achieve it I am following this way, If any better alter way is there please suggest me. And further I can't change the existed framework

Comment: @user3620283: I've added to the end of the answer. But fundamentally: There are libraries for this, I'd use one rather than trying to reinvent it. :-) (And ES6 will make things even more powerful, via the new `Proxy` objects.)

Comment: @Crowder: Thanks again for the code snippet. Here the problem is the function A.ao will be invoked from so many places (classes + different files). And even from different functions (diff func names). so the answer may not solve my problem though I like the approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a method in the object which returns its type. Another option is to use `instanceof` and check for all possible types.

```
function A() {
    this.getType = function () {
        return "A";
    }
}

A.prototype.ao = function() {
    // Here I want ot know the fucntion caller class name, for that I used
    var type = this.getType();
    args.callee.caller.prototype; // It retuens B.bo {} (object)
}

function B(){
    this.getType = function () {
        return "B";
    }
}

B.prototype.bo = function(){
    var a = new A();
    a.ao.apply(this);
}
```

Here you will also have to redefine `getType` in all of your inherited types and return the correct type. You also need to invoke the desired method with `apply(this)` to provide the context of the current caller.

Comment: But the caller is `B.bo`, not `A`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have updated the answer. One thing that was missing was applying the method called with the context of the current caller.